# Need advice regarding AJAX and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a situation where i have 3 multiselects, say level1,level2 and level3
now, level2 depends on the option selected in level1 and similarly level3 depends on the option selected in level2
My question is that is it better to get all the data in one go that is when the page loads and filter this data using jquery depending on the option selected by the user OR should i make ajax based request to the database to fetch the data for the next multiselect each time user selects an options.
which approach would be better??

Comment: depends on how many options there are.

Comment: concur with red-X. if there are not many options the AJAX is pointless and limits accessibility for non-JS users

Comment: If there are a lot of options, it would be better to make a request every time, otherwise, just load them all in the beginning. It really depends, if you're not sure you should try both options and check the time it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer would be that it depends on the amount of data shown.

If the amount of data in level1, level2, level3 is relatively small - you'd benefit from retrieving all the data: you'll save the load to the server by reducing a number of requests. This will make you write some javascript, but the filling of the lists will be lightning fast.

On the other hand, if your tree has a lot of data (i.e. 100 level1 items, each one has 100 level2 items, each of which has 100 level3 items), you'll end up in transferring a million of items (huge overhead for this usecase), and the good solution for this case is a separate AJAX call for each list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make ajax call to fetch data from database on every selection.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax, depending on your server speed, is a really fast technology, because it's asynchronous (no postback needed), and because of how data is transfered. 
I would say that depends on the amount of the records. You should use your programmer criteria here. I mean, if the combo has lots of options and the server is slow or it's on the other side of the world, bring it all at first time. Either way you can keep calling ajax functions on combo change event.

Use your criteria-

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have the choice to combine multiple requests into one then that is the best option.  Each request utilizes more resources, which can be unnecessary.  Granted, this depends solely on the type of data that you are handling, as it may not be possible to get all of the available options in one go or it may just be too much extra data to load.

Answer (score 0):

To an extent, it depends on how much data you're talking about.

For reasonably small amounts -- a few KB worth -- you should absolutely download it all at once. It's faster to reorganize it client-side than to wait for an AJAX query to pull it down, and you'll have fewer hits on the server -- especially if the user might be clicking around and sending several AJAX requests in a row.

If you've got a major application that requires several MB of data for a single download, then smaller AJAX queries are probably the way to go.

In between, it's a judgment call, but I would always lean toward a single download and client-side sorting. Anything that minimizes or eliminates the delay resulting from a new request-and-response is good.

Comment: the data which is being fetched is in total around 100KB so what do you suggest. For now i tried using jquery doesn't seem to have any problems atleast on my local machine and the page also seems to be loading fine. what do you suggest

Comment: How about a compromise? Load the page except for the data, then get the entire 100KB chunk of data in a single AJAX query. That way you're minimizing server requests, but the user isn't waiting for the page to load. Hide the first scrollbox until the AJAX query is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the ajax based request to the database because debugging and manipulation of the data will be easier if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use **Jquery**.
and you should load data after every selection in multiselect. 
performance wise it is not a good approach to load all the data on page load ..